# I can't add edges to my network graph made in the igraph in R

Tags: graph, igraph, network-analysis

I am trying to make a network graph through the igraph, but only the nodes appear, the edges / links do not appear. My data comes from an adjacency matrix. And I don't know where the problem is. Does anyone know how I can add the edges?

Here is my script:

```
    library(igraph)

data = structure(list(Adenocalymma_adenophorum = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.003122927, 
0.00999241, 0.008685473, 0.007730365, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.003573423, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Adenocalymma_cf_bracteosum = c(0L, 
NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Adenocalymma_flaviflorum = c(0L, 0L, 
NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Adenocalymma_japurensis = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Adenocalymma_longilinium = c(0.18893711, 0, 
0, 0, NA, 0.183237263, 0.139293056, 0.120902907, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.132071652, 0, 0.457142857, 0.114500717
), Adenocalymma_moringifolium = c(0.322255215, 0, 0, 0, 0.097676062, 
NA, 0.261095249, 0.131416203, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.146191646, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Adenocalymma_neoflavidum = c(0.086854728, 0, 0, 
0, 0.023023646, 0.080959767, NA, 0.034786642, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Adenocalymma_tanaeciicarpum = c(0.09469697, 
0, 0, 0, 0.024480341, 0.049917782, 0.042613636, NA, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.255554962, 0, 0, 0, 0), Amphilophium_parkeri = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Anemopaegma_robustum = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Bignonia_aequinoctialis = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), Bignonia_prieurei = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), Calichlamys_latifolia = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Fridericia_cf_trailli = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.765625, 
    0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Fridericia_chica = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fridericia_cinamomea = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fridericia_nigrescens = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fridericia_prancei = c(0.040201005, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), Fridericia_triplinervia = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.041930937, 
    0, 0.192970073, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), Pachyptera_aromatica = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.030562035, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0), Pleonotoma_albiflora = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L), Pleonotoma_melioides = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.151121606, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0.039751553), Tynanthus_panurensis = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.026693325, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.011428571, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Adenocalymma_adenophorum", 
"Adenocalymma_cf_bracteosum", "Adenocalymma_flaviflorum", "Adenocalymma_japurensis", 
"Adenocalymma_longilinium", "Adenocalymma_moringifolium", "Adenocalymma_neoflavidum", 
"Adenocalymma_tanaeciicarpum", "Amphilophium_parkeri", "Anemopaegma_robustum", 
"Bignonia_aequinoctialis", "Bignonia_prieurei", "Calichlamys_latifolia", 
"Fridericia_cf_trailli", "Fridericia_chica", "Fridericia_cinamomea", 
"Fridericia_nigrescens", "Fridericia_prancei", "Fridericia_triplinervia", 
"Pachyptera_aromatica", "Pleonotoma_albiflora", "Pleonotoma_melioides", 
"Tynanthus_panurensis"))

View (data)

class (data)

data= data.matrix(data, rownames.force = NA) # 
class (data)

network <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix (data)


plot(network, edge.arrow.size=.5, vertex.color="gold", vertex.size=15, 
     vertex.frame.color="gray", vertex.label.color="black", 
     vertex.label.cex=0.8, vertex.label.dist=2, edge.curved=0.2)
```

When I run the network, the following appears:

```
IGRAPH 52a911a DN-- 23 0 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges from 52a911a (vertex names)
```

My graph:
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgIyc.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Please use `dput(data)` to share your data in the post.

Comment: I edited and placed the data so that it is reproducible. Sorry I didn't do this before, this is my first time using the forum. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should enable the argument options `mode =` and `weighted`

```
graph <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(data, mode = "directed", weighted = TRUE)
```

and then `plot(graph)` gives you
[image]